# Yii2 Active record how create relation between mongo models

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I have 2 classes which extends`\yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord`
for example `Users` and `Posts` relations between this classes User have many posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as using relational databases:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Posts::className(),['_id'=>'user_id']);
}
```