# Yii2 MongoDB query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, yii2

I was using MySQL for my db before and moved to using MongoDB just recently. I have been converting my queries to MongoDB format then I encountered a problem along the way.

I wanted to get the `payslip_id` of a specific user where `date_generated` (of the payslip) is in between the start and end dates of a specific payroll period. Here's the original query (MySQL):

```
public function getPayslipDetails()
{  
    $time = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $time = date('Y/m/d', time());
    $session = Yii::$app->session; 

    return $this->hasOne(Payslip::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id'])->where('date_generated BETWEEN :start_time AND :end_time', array(':start_time' => $session['start'], ':end_time' => $session['end'])); 
}

public function getPayslipID() 
{    
    return $this->payslipDetails ? $this->payslipDetails->payslip_id : '';
}
```

Now, here's my converted query to MongoDB:

```
public function getPayslipDetails()
{  
    $time = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $time = date('Y/m/d', time());
    $session = Yii::$app->session; 

    return $this->hasOne(Payslip::className(), ['user_id' => '_id'])->where(array('date_generated' =>  array('$in' => array($session['start'], $session['end']))));  
}

public function getPayslipID() 
{    
    return $this->payslipDetails ? $this->payslipDetails->_id : '';
}
```

Notice the return statements are different. I wonder if my MongoDB query is correct or not. It doesn't return any error as well.

I would really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array. It is not equivalent to MySQL`BETWEEN`.

Use [`$gte`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#gte) and [`$lte`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/#lte) operators.

```
public function getPayslipDetails()
{  
    $time = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $time = date('Y/m/d', time());
    $session = Yii::$app->session; 

    return $this->hasOne(Payslip::className(), ['user_id' => '_id'])->where(array('date_generated' =>  array('$gte' => $session['start']), 'date_generated' =>  array('$lte' => $session['end'])));  
}

public function getPayslipID() 
{    
    return $this->payslipDetails ? $this->payslipDetails->_id : '';
}
```

I am not sure about the syntax of php-mongodb but I think this should help.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347016/yii2-active-record-how-create-relation-between-mongo-models do you know how to use function `getPosts` in view?